# How to recreate the 'take' function by list comprehension in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, list-comprehension

The below code recreate the 'take' function in Haskell by recursion:

```
take' :: Int->[a]->[a]
take' 0 _=[]
take' _ []= []
take' n (x:xs)=x : take' (n-1) xs
```

I want to create 'take' function using list comprehension:

```
take' n a=[x|x<-a]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the ParallelListComp extension, a list comprehension can zip:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}

take' n a = [x | x <- a | _ <- [1..n]]
```

Comment: Even without that extension, you can write `[x | (x,_) <- zip a [1..n]]`.

Comment: @chepner: But then you’re using `zip`, which I think kind of defeats the point. (Maybe it doesn’t.)

Comment: Why? The OP just asked for a list comprehension; they didn't put any restrictions on what could be used inside.

Comment: @Ry- From my point of view, `zip` and parallel comprehensions are roughly the same. If the object of the game is to use comprehension syntax, then parallel comprehension looks closer to the spirit. I guess that the OP aimed for plain comprehensions and no library functions, but that is impossible.